# Google Analytics Embed API getting error when implementing with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, google-analytics-api

I already sended data from my angular project to Google Analytics. Now I am trying to retrieve data from Google Analytics using the Google Analytics api with the Embed api.  I want to display it in my angular application i followed this tutorial [Embed API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/interactive-charts/) but i'm getting error in console from this line which is in my index.html file :

```
js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
```

Can i get some help please how to fix that error and render my google analytics
data in my angular view !

## index.html

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
       <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-192522348-1"></script>
       <script>
           window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
   
           function gtag() {
               dataLayer.push(arguments);
           }
           gtag('js', new Date());
   
       </script>
       <script>
         (function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
           g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
           js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
           js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
           fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
         }(window,document,'script'));
         </script>
```

## analytics.componenet.ts

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
   
       gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
       console.log("finished loading");
         /**
          * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
          * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
          * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
          */
         gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
           container: "embed-api-auth-container",
           clientid: <<here my client id>>
           
         
         });
       
        /**
          * Create a new ViewSelector instance to be rendered inside of an
          * element with the id "view-selector-container".
          */
         var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
           container: 'view-selector-container'
         });
       
         // Render the view selector to the page.
         viewSelector.execute();
       
         /**
          * Create a table chart showing top browsers for users to interact with.
          * Clicking on a row in the table will update a second timeline chart with
          * data from the selected browser.
          */
         var mainChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
           query: {
             'dimensions': 'ga:browser',
             'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
             'sort': '-ga:sessions',
             'max-results': '6'
           },
           chart: {
             type: 'TABLE',
             container: 'main-chart-container',
             options: {
               width: '100%'
             }
           }
         });
       
       
        
       
         /**
          * Store a refernce to the row click listener variable so it can be
          * removed later to prevent leaking memory when the chart instance is
          * replaced.
          */
         var mainChartRowClickListener;
       
       
         /**
          * Update both charts whenever the selected view changes.
          */
         viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
           var options = {query: {ids: ids}};
       
           // Clean up any event listeners registered on the main chart before
           // rendering a new one.
           if (mainChartRowClickListener) {
             google.visualization.events.removeListener(mainChartRowClickListener);
           }
       
           mainChart.set(options).execute();
         
       
           // Only render the breakdown chart if a browser filter has been set.
          
         });
       
       
         /**
          * Each time the main chart is rendered, add an event listener to it so
          * that when the user clicks on a row, the line chart is updated with
          * the data from the browser in the clicked row.
          */
         mainChart.on('success', function(response) {
       
           var chart = response.chart;
           var dataTable = response.dataTable;
       
           // Store a reference to this listener so it can be cleaned up later.
           mainChartRowClickListener = google.visualization.events
               .addListener(chart, 'select', function(event) {
       
             // When you unselect a row, the "select" event still fires
             // but the selection is empty. Ignore that case.
             if (!chart.getSelection().length) return;
       
             var row =  chart.getSelection()[0].row;
             var browser =  dataTable.getValue(row, 0);
             var options = {
               query: {
                 filters: 'ga:browser==' + browser
               },
               chart: {
                 options: {
                   title: browser
                 }
               }
             };
       
             
           });
         });
     
       
       });
   
     }
```

## analytics.componenet.html

```
<div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div> <div
   id="view-selector-container"></div> <div
   id="main-chart-container"></div> <div
   id="breakdown-chart-container"></div>
```

## error i get in the console

[image]

> 4071097310-idpiframe.js:158
> Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function
> at T (4071097310-idpiframe.js:158)
> at ai.m.Hf (4071097310-idpiframe.js:201)
> at Object.C (4071097310-idpiframe.js:205)
> at Ah.Mf (4071097310-idpiframe.js:182)
> at b (4071097310-idpiframe.js:193) ```

Comment: Have you tried searching SO. There are a lot of questions related to "indexOf is not a function"

Comment: @DaImTo yes i've tried it but i can't get where is the problem exactly to solve it !

Answer (score 0):

In the docs, under the large code snippet at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started#copy-and-paste, it says:

> Important: make sure your HTML pages have a doctype declared. The Embed API does not support quirksmode.

In short, you should add `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your html document to ensure the browser does not revert to "quirks mode", which this API is apparently incompatible with.